# generating (executable) code dynamically

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern, local-variables

I have a function that accepts two Strings

```
void setStringValue(String varname,String varValue){
   //I am trying to do something crazy and change an extern variables' value here
   extern String varname;
   varname = varValue;

   //And 
   extern String varname = varValue;// throws errors
}
```

but i have to define a String called varname for this to even compile. Problem is that doing so means only the local varname gets modified to hold varValue;

How can i change the name of the extern and assign it a value dynamically?

This is a snippet from arduino code the full thing includes 
a main sketch

```
String testString;
//Instantiating the class with the snippet
Snippet changeString(Serial); // uses serial to print to console
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
}
```

The function setStringValue gets called when something is written on the serial monitor. After writting comma separated name value (name,value) i then pass this to the function. parameter name being the name i assigned to the global string in the sketch and its value after the comma.

I then want to create an extern String called whatever value thats first parameter and assign it a value of the second parameter.

Currently when i pass a testString,"Changed" on the serial monitor it prints a blank space.

Comment: Certainly looks like you are heading down a rabbit hole here. Can we see what you are trying to accomplish in action so we can maybe suggest a different path?

Comment: Please adjust your title.  Are you creating variables dynamically or are you generating (executable) code dynamically?  They are two different concepts.

Comment: generating (executable) code dynamically. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a variable's name as a target at runtime. You can't do that in C++ because it is a compiled language. You _can_ do that kind of thing in an interpreted language like Python, Ruby, or SNOBOL4.

Comment: @user4581301 all editted with new information

Comment: You cannot change the name of a variable. Once the code is compiled, those pretty names are gone, replaced with memory addresses and offsets. [But you can have a std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of name and value, in this case `std::map<String, String> names;` that you can use to recover the value at name with `String value = names[name];`

Comment: If you are generating executable code dynamically, you will need to embed a compiler into your code or call the compiler to generate the executable.  I don't think this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be a variation of wanting to call a function at runtime by modifying a variable. eg.

```C++
int whichFunction = 42;
foo + whichFunction ();   // call foo42;
```

You can't do that.

---

You appear to be wanting:

```C++
String foo;
setStringValue ("foo", "bar");  // set variable foo to bar
```

You can't do that either. In neither case does the executable code know the variable or function names and thus you can't use variable names like that at runtime.

---

You can work around that to an extent. For example your function `setStringValue` might look like this:

```C++
void setStringValue(String varname,String varValue){
  if (varname == "foo")
    foo = varValue;
  else if (varname == "bar")
    bar = varValue;     
}
```

Or, you could have a table that maps names to addresses. Then scan the table, find a matching name, and set the corresponding variable.